# How can one trust geometric proofs if humans are susceptible to optical illusions?

Tags: geometry, fake-proofs

How can one make a proof that doesn't consist of a bunch of symbolic manipulations "formal"?

Comment: That's not an *optical* illusion.  That is a faulty reasoning from misunderstanding limits and measuring distances.

Comment: @fleablood I removed the image. Though I'm still curious about the question in general when geometric images are not being added simply to aid intuition but take up an actual part of the proof

Comment: I wouldn't have removed the images.  It's an interesting and illuminating false proof.  And with examples your question is far too vague to have any useful answer.

Comment: @fleablood Should I delete my question then?

Comment: No.  If you have a question you should ask it.  A "meta-question" like this is not invalidated when someone like me points out why a false proof fails.  The question *isn't* about whether the math is correct or not, but about how we reason.  So you really should not take my comments as a correction.

Comment: @fleablood Sorry

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for.

Comment: One example was Kempe's 'proof' of the 4-colour theorem, which was based on [diagram-based reasoning](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2014_15/math_honors_f2014/math_honors_f2014_lecture4.pdf) and found to be flawed more than a decade later. Basically, without a formal symbolic proof you cannot have 100% guarantee about correctness of a proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't fully trust picture proofs. Any rigorous proof can be expressed as a bunch of symbolic manipulations. Some authors have even avoided drawing pictures to make this point.

It's usually far more enlightening to visualize the ideas, though. On that note you might be interested in reading the "Lockhart's Lament" essay.